# What is the subject for the sentence "kind of"?

Tags: subjects

The sentence here

> Kind of makes me wish that I had parents who would arrange a marriage for me if my love life fails. - *[discussion about marriage in india](https://www.quora.com/Do-girls-have-the-freedom-to-get-friendly-with-a-boy-and-marry-him-in-India-Sri-Lanka-Pakistan-and-Bangladesh)*

**makes** here is predicate verb， Is **Kind of**, which is at the beginning of the sentence is subject? **Kind of** is not a noun: how can it be a subject for the sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In informal speech, words that are obvious from the context are frequently omitted: this is called [converstational deletion](https://learnenglishwithdemi.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/conversational-deletion/). In this case, the omitted word is **it**.

> It [kind of] makes me wish that ...

**[Kind of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kind_of)** is an adverbal phrase meaning **to some extent**.

Answer (score 1):

The subject has been omitted in this informal sentence. The subject is probably "It", meaning "this situation" - "This situation (kind of) makes me wish ...". We could also use "this" or "that".
Subject pronouns are often omitted in informal speech or writing.